# Thermal expansion

Tags: thermodynamics

When two bodies made of same material with same external appearance and dimension, one is hollow while next is solid. If heated, will overall volume expansion be same or different ?

Comment: Are these objects subject to air pressure on their external and/or internal surfaces?  It matters...

Answer (score 0):

They should both expand the same i.e the hollow object will expand as much as the solid. The molecules in the shell of the hollow will expand and stretch the same distance as the molecules on the surface of the hollow when thermal energy is applied. I hope this answers your question!

Comment: But as i came to know , the hollow one will have more volume expansion because when same amount of heat is applied to both of them; the solid one having more mass will have small rise in temp. while the hollow one will have more rise in temp. . And we know that when all other factor are same then the only factor that affects the final volume is rise in temp. i.e. V2 = V1(1+Gamma× delta theta).

Comment: As far as I am aware the expansion is mainly dependent on the material rather than the air inside.

Comment: Yeah of course. Expansion depends upon the material rather than air inside. And by the way, by volume I meant volume of the material not the air inside

Answer (score 0):

The expansion is defined by the temperature increase and the material coefficient of thermal expansion (CTE).

If heated to the same temperature, the expansion will be identical.

If same energy is added to both, the hollow will expand more because it will have a larger temperature increase.